# Por que mi aplicacion de flutter se ejecuta mas lento en dispositivos fisicos?

Tags: flutter

Hola a todos me encuentro desarrollando una app en flutter utilizando la dependencia blue_thermal_printer y cuando ejecuto la aplicacion en un emulador se comporta de forma natural pero al hacerlo en un dispositivo fisico la aplicacion se trabab y va muy lento pese a que el dispositivo tenga mejores caracteristicas que el emulador. Quisiera saber si el problema esta relacionado con respecto a si es por que lo sigo ejecutando en debug o sea un problema de rendimiento, como soy nuevo en flutter no se hacia donde indica el error.
Donde principalmente la aplicacion se muestra mas lenta es en esta parte donde agrego a las celdas unos botones d eincremento y decremento:

````
    final productInfo = productData[flavor]![presentation];
    return DataCell(
       Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () {
              if (productInfo != null && productInfo.quantity > 0) {
                setState(() {
                  productInfo.quantity--;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 29,
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              controller: TextEditingController(
                text: productInfo?.quantity.toString() ?? '0',
              ),
              onSubmitted: (newValue) {
                final newQuantity = int.tryParse(newValue) ?? 0;
                setState(() {
                  productInfo?.quantity = newQuantity;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              if (productInfo != null) {
                setState(() {
                  productInfo.quantity++;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } ```
````